# Why is my powershell custom property null after reading in this CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv, class

Given the code below, if any of the status in my CSV file occur exactly 1 time the value for the 'num' property will be 'blank' instead of '1'. Now, if I there are at least two of the same status within the CSV file, the 'num' property value will be '2'. Finally, if there are NO instances of the given status in the CSV file, the 'num' property value will '0'. I am having a hard time debugging why a single instance will not show up correctly within the 'num' property value?

```
$DataSource = "foo.csv"

Class PieChartClass {
    $Status
    $Num
}
    
$Statuses = 'Installed', 'Decommissioned', 'In Stock', 'Removed'

$Results = {}.Invoke()

Foreach($Status in $Statuses){
    $Computers = Get-Content $ServiceNowDataSource | ConvertFrom-Csv | Where-Object {$_.install_status -eq $Status}
    $Result = [PieChartClass]::new()
    $Result.Status = $Status
    $Result.Num = $Computers.count
    $Results.Add($Result)
}

$Results
```

CSV File structure as follows:

```
"name","asset","discovery_source","install_status"
"pc001","laptop","foo","Decommissioned"
"pc002","laptop","foo","Installed"
"pc003","tablet","foo","Installed"
"pc004","tablet","bar","Installed"
"pc005","laptop","bar","Decommissioned"
"pc006","desktop","bar","Removed"
```

The value of $Results given the CSV file is:

```
Status         Num
------         ---
Installed        3
Decommissioned   2
In Stock         0
Removed
```

Why in the world does 'Removed' show [BLANK]?

I appreciate any insight into this bug.

Comment: hum because $ServiceNowDataSource is different of $Datasource may be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose you an other method :

```
Class PieChartClass {
    $Status
    $Num
}

$Statuses = 'Installed', 'Decommissioned', 'In Stock', 'Removed'

#Import data and group by install_status, better in perf because you dont load to every loop
$Results=import-csv "c:\temp\foo.csv" -Delimiter "," | group install_status | %{
$Result = [PieChartClass]::new()
$Result.Status = $_.Name
$Result.Num = $_.Group.count
$Result
}

#for add element with 0 elements
$Statuses | where {$_ -notin $Results.Status} | %{
$Result = [PieChartClass]::new()
$Result.Status = $_
$Result.Num = 0
$Results+=$Result
}

$Results
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestion here will work. Would just like to have understood why it didn't work to begin with. It had nothing to do with the variable name as your pointed out above as that was merely a typo on my behalf. But im still glad this seems be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If is not necessary to have PieChartClass and empty install_status elements you can quicly do it :

```
import-csv "c:\temp\foo.csv" -Delimiter "," | group install_status | %{[pscustomobject]@{Status=$_.Name;Num=$_.Group.count}}
```

or better

```
import-csv "c:\temp\foo.csv" -Delimiter "," | group install_status | select Name, Count
```